# Android app is crashing due to disabled google cloud billing account

Tags: android, google-cloud-console, google-cloud-billing

My Android app is crashing due to a disabled Google Cloud billing account. After enabling it the app is still crashing.

I created a new billing account for Google Cloud and linked it with my project. By doing this it upgraded my firebase plan from spark to blaze. Does it mean it will now charge my account (I am only using free Google Cloud services)? What other steps do I need to follow regarding the Google Cloud console & Google Play store? kindly suggest any settings that I need to modify. Is it possible to resolve this issue without giving an update to my app on the Play Store?

I am getting the following error:
Caused by: com.google.maps.errors.RequestDeniedException: You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started

Comment: This error is from Google Maps (A Google cloud service). Your Google Maps API limit has been reached. Enable billing from your Google Cloud console. Note one thing, Google cloud is different from Firebase, and Google Maps is a service of Google Cloud. Enable billing of your Google Maps, it'll get resolved automatically.

Comment: I have 2 billing accounts- Google Cloud platform and Google Maps platform. Which billing account do I need to link with my project(which uses Google Maps SDK)?

Comment: I tried both accounts but still I am getting the same console error.

Comment: This Request Denied exception is from Google Maps. So, enable billing for Google Maps service. Is Google Maps billing different from Google Cloud billing?

Comment: Yes, both are different. Maps billing is done in $ and Cloud billing is done in INR.

Comment: Is that resolved or still an error??

Comment: it is resolved now. thank you.

Comment: Kindly post your response to my question, so that I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Can you share with me where it occurred and how you resolved it?

Comment: I was getting this error when my maps fragment was being called. I linked my Google Maps billing account with my project and created a new API credential. By doing these steps I can load my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned your question, `Caused by: com.google.maps.errors.RequestDeniedException: You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started`

This exception is occurred due to from Google Maps API limit reached. So, enable billing for your Google Maps SDK. It'll get resolved.

@ruhi-viroja:- I linked my Google Maps billing account with my project and created a new API credential. By doing these steps I can load my app.